# PHP class_exists() cannot find a class that truly exists

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces, autoload

I am trying to write a CakePHP Authentication plugin and am following and structuring it after this repository: https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth

I am still at the early stages, trying to get my plugin to load during cakePHPs `constructAuthenticate()` method. I have narrowed down my issue to this method never finding my class when it calls `class_exists()`

I have Project structure as follows:

`App/
    plugins/
    src/
        Controller/
            AppController.php
        Model/
    vendor/
        Admad/
            cakephp-jwt-auth/
                src/
                    Auth/
                        JwtAuthenticate.php
                composer.json
        nates/
            cakephp-total-auth/
                src/
                    Auth/
                        TotalAuthenticate.php
                composer.json`

`TotalAuthenticate` is the class I'm trying to load, and it's namespace as defined in `TotalAuthenticate.php` is:

`namespace nates\TotalAuth\auth;`

After some debugging I have found that the Path being passed to `classs_exists()` is:

`nates\TotalAuth\Auth\TotalAuthenticate`

I have compared all of this info to the `Admad/JwtAuth` plugin and the relative paths all match up, and that plugin loads just fine so I'm really at a loss at whats going on here and why my plugin won't load.

My Autoload in `App/composer.json` Looks as such:

```
`"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Test\\": "tests/",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/"
        }
    },`
```

And my Plugins `composer.json` :

```
`"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "nates\\TotalAuth\\": "src"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
//      "ADmad\\JwtAuth\\Test\\": "tests"
    }`
```

Comment: What's in your `composer.json` autoload?

Comment: @ccKep Thanks for taking a look at this.  I have updated the question with both my App/composer.json and my Plugin/composer.json as I did not know which one you wanted to see

Comment: @ccKep I was playing around with the ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth plugin, (The one that loads correctly) and I was able to break it's loading and fix it again.  That lead me to find that my Plugin (nates/TotalAuth) is not listed in the autoload_static.php file while ADmad is.  Could this be why PHP doesn't recognize my class? Should I even be editing this autoload_static.php file directly?

Comment: You should **not** edit that file directly, it's created by `composer dump-autoload` - so run that command.

Answer (score 0):

PSR-4 autoloading standard requires that the namespace matches the file structure case-sensitive. You define your namespace in `composer.json` with capitals `nates\TotalAuth`, but in your class as `nates\totalauth\...`.

Make sure all casings match and the casings match the file structure.

Comment: Sorry that was an issue of me typing it on SO.  Casings all match

Comment: I was playing around with the ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth plugin, (The one that loads correctly) and I was able to break it's loading and fix it again. That lead me to find that my Plugin (nates/TotalAuth) is not listed in the autoload_static.php file while ADmad is. Could this be why PHP doesn't recognize my class? Should I even be editing this autoload_static.php file directly?